# Angular / Ionic 5 guard for navigation pop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, guard

I have an Angular / Ionic 5 app with a view which shows a video stream. From this view, we can navigate to:

1. Views which get **pushed** onto the stack. This way the video will simply continue running in the background, which is great and intended,
2. Navigate back or navigate to other views via `routerDirection="root"`, where the video view is **popped** from the stack, and thus the video will stop running.

We want to avoid that the user accidentally disconnects from the video in case (2), by showing a confirmation dialog.

This would obviously typically be done through a `CanDeactivate` guard. However, this guard currently shows both, in case (1) **and** (2).

Is there any way to detect (within the guard, or elsewhere) if the navigation would **remove** resp. **pop** the current view from the stack, so that I can act accordingly and only show the dialog in this case?

[edit] The solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397817/388827) using the `NavController`’s `direction` seems like a good start, however this does not cover push/pop events 1:1 unfortunately.